# Java, separator between JMenuBar and other components

Tags: java, separator, jmenubar

in Java Swing how can I change the color of the separator between `JMenuBar` and other components. Alternatively I would like to remove the separator.

Comment: can you post screenshot? you mean border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIU:

```
jMenuBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
```